# Convert author metadata to a custom field

Tags: custom-field, author

I have an old wordpress (newspaper) with hundreds of different authors but just one person that works in the backend to post the new articles. Every time he has to create a new author in order (with name, email...) in order to post a new article, every time he has a new author.

Now I'll have to work on the cms to make it a 2021 website and i wonder if there is a simple way to convert all the old authors (400 or more) in something different, like a field in a personalized field group, linkable to an "author" archive, in order to make some order in the site archive and to make the future work of publishing easier. They usually have more than one user for post, and actually use a "multiauthor" plugin that make the website very slow.
Thanks in advance!
Lucio

Comment: what is this multi-author plugin you mentioned? It's not very clear what the question is, just that it's related to authors, an unknown plugin, and post meta

Comment: Hello Tom, they actually use this plugin https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/
They have 700+ authors, but just one person that everytime they have a new. author creates a new profile, edit the post and assigns it to the new author.

I'd like to create a custom post field called "Authors" and populate it with the names of the authors (old posts too) in order to make in the future the work of publishing new posts easier.